# How to set combobox selected value in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, combobox, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and I have an update/edit form which include a combobox on it. But I can't set my combobox value depends on what in the database. Do you know how to do it?

Here is my controller:

```
public function ubahsurat(Request $request)
{
    Surat::where('nomor_surat', '=', $request['nomor_surat'])->update(
                            ['id_jenis_surat' => $request['id_jenis_surat']],

    return redirect('/');
}
```

This is the view:

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">
         <select name="id_jenis_surat" class="form-control">
         <option></option>
            @foreach($jenis_surat as $js) 
            <option value="{{ $js->id_jenis_surat }}" > {{ $js->jenis_surat }} </option> 
            @endforeach
        </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set `selected="selected"` on the item which is active.

```
<option value="{{ $js->id_jenis_surat }}" {!! ($conditionForSelected ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") !!}> {{ $js->jenis_surat }}</option>
```

Replace `$conditionForSelected` with whatever it is that determines if `$js->id_jenis_surat` is the current item that is selected.

Your view is showing us the update code, not the view code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
   <div class="col-sm-9">
     <select name="id_jenis_surat" class="form-control">
     <option></option>
        @foreach($jenis_surat as $js) 
        <option value="{{ $js->id_jenis_surat }}" @if($combobox_value_from_database==$js->id_jenis_surat) selected="selected" @endif> {{ $js->jenis_surat }} </option> 
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

**Note**: I would encourage you to use Laravel Form Builders. so you can avoid handling these type of issues.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean "$value_from_database"

Comment: You asked in your question "But I can't set my combo-box value depends on what in the database". you saved a value into the database right? And you want that particular  value to be selected on edit, right? so you will fetch all values that need to be populated into the edit fields, including the value of combo-box. I just given a variable to indicate that value is from database, as we are not provided with the data you send to the view. :-) see my updated answer. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please note that what @Jaw.sh did is also right and in shortest form.